# Npx create-react-app not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I installed create react app globally. And then i ran

Npx create-react-app jsx

It installed all of the packages around 1460 packages.But it didn't setup the public and src folders. In my jsx folder there is only
1:Node modules
2:package.json
3:package.lock.json

Public folder and src folder are missing.
And aslo script "Npm start" doesn't work.
Am i missing something?
Note: I'm using the latest version od node, npm, npx.
I've tried 2-3 times but everytime the folders are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before and i tried this before and it works for me:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-react-app
```